# Reprovision a user in AD using OIM 11 R2

Tags: oim

i have a user in oim who i need to provision in AD. The existing AD Instance was stuck in provisioning.  I need to know how to force oim to re provision this AD instance.  i have already revoked the previous instance and went requested another instance but its still in the provisioning state.

Answer (score 1):

You can't revoke the one which stuck in Provisioning. You can try to troubleshoot why your first one has not finished the provisioning process. Check the resource history, if you want to do that.

You can request another one account regardless of the first one, but if the root reason for the failure of the first one is still there, you will end with the same result. So both of your accounts will be in Provisioning.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the Open Tasks to find out why the create failed, and perhaps modify the process form to include the attributes that are missing.(If there are any)

Look also in the UD_ADUSER table in the notes column.  This will show what prepopulate adaptors worked.  If the notes aren't populated there is potentially something else (System Validation?) that needs completed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope till now you might have found out the root cause.But incase if anyone needs,here is the practice that i follow:

Since both of your request were in provisioning state,seems there is an issue with your provisioning workflow.

Go step by step to find out the cause of the failure.

1. If your task is in System Validation state,then you will have to cross verify all the required attributes if they are populated or not and whether there value is as expected by AD.
2. Find out the reason to why it went in provisioning,so as to avoid the future failures.To do this you can retry the failed task of that instance from resource history,monitor the logs at the same time. From oim-diagnostic.log ,for sure will get a hint.And then try to troubleshoot in that direction.
3. Check UD_ADUSER table's note column to verify if all the prepopulate adapters were completed.
4. You can also check the connector server logs in case you don't get any help from the oim logs.

   And one more thing,you cannot revoke the account in Provisioning State.